# How to invoke an external server?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have created the apex class after generated from WSDl file. Now i need to do "Invoking an external server". I am new to this, how to do this invoking. Kindly tell the link about this .

Comment: http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Apex_Web_Services_and_Callouts

Answer (score 1):

This [link](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_callouts_wsdl2apex.htm) has a good example of using Apex Classes which are generated from WSDLs.
You might also want to refer this [link](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Apex_Web_Services_and_Callouts#WSDL2Apex).

Answer (score 0):

```
 public class DocSamplePort {

    public String endpoint_x = 'http://YourServer/YourService';

    private String[] ns_map_type_info = new String[]{
                         'http://doc.sample.com/docSample', 
                         'docSample'};

    public String EchoString(String input) {
        docSample.EchoString_element request_x = 
                           new docSample.EchoString_element();
        docSample.EchoStringResponse_element response_x;
        request_x.input = input;
        Map<String, docSample.EchoStringResponse_element> response_map_x = 
                  new Map<String, docSample.EchoStringResponse_element>();
        response_map_x.put('response_x', response_x);
        WebServiceCallout.invoke(
          this,
          request_x,
          response_map_x,
          new String[]{endpoint_x,
             'urn:dotnet.callouttest.soap.sforce.com/EchoString',
             'http://doc.sample.com/docSample',
             'EchoString',
             'http://doc.sample.com/docSample',
             'EchoStringResponse',
             'docSample.EchoStringResponse_element'}
        );
        response_x = response_map_x.get('response_x');
        return response_x.EchoStringResult;
    }
```

In your class just search for the WebServiceCallout.invoke method .Now the class holding the method is your stub class and You need to invoke the method after instantiating the stub class and filling the parameters as expected by method .

In the above example DocSamplePort is a class and hence we will instantiate this

```
docSample.DocSamplePort stub = new docSample.DocSamplePort();
```

Now we need to invoke the method EchoString

```
String input = 'This is the input string';
String output = stub.EchoString(input);
```

Once we invoke the method we will get the result as per return parameter of the invoke method .Hope this helps